# OWB wb_rt_constants definition

Tags: oracle, oracle-warehouse-builder

I am am trying to understand a piece of SQL which I cannot execute unfortunately . I am stuck on one part of code where

```
     wb_rt_constants.to_string (e.audit_status) AS audit_status_symbol
```

I cannot seem to find what wb_rt_constants.to_string does ? is it some sort of decode ? Can some one explain what

> wb_rt_constants.to_string

is trying to do , preferably definition of wb_rt_constants.to_string will be highly appreciated   ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the package body `OWBSYS.wb_rt_constants` is wrapped so we can't see the source code of its implementation.

Anyway, the function `to_string` has the following signature:

```
function to_string(p_constant in number) return varchar2;
```

It is used in some OWBSYS views, such as `ALL_RT_AUDIT_EXECUTIONS` and seems to translate a numeric ID into a descriptive string, e.g.

```
col execution_audit_status format a20

select distinct e.audit_status,
       wb_rt_constants.to_string(e.audit_status) as execution_audit_status
  from wb_rt_audit_executions e;

AUDIT_STATUS EXECUTION_AUDIT_STAT
------------ --------------------
       16002 BUSY
       16004 COMPLETE
```

Those numbers seems to match the output of these functions of the same package:

```
select wb_rt_constants.EXECUTION_STATUS_INACTIVE,
       wb_rt_constants.EXECUTION_STATUS_BUSY,
       wb_rt_constants.EXECUTION_STATUS_READY,
       wb_rt_constants.EXECUTION_STATUS_COMPLETE
  from dual;

EXECUTION_STATUS_INACTIVE EXECUTION_STATUS_BUSY EXECUTION_STATUS_READY EXECUTION_STATUS_COMPLETE
------------------------- --------------------- ---------------------- -------------------------
                    16001                 16002                  16003                     16004
```